# PHP 7.0 pg_query_params(): null gets converted to empty string, but only after looping with a reference

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm updating a project from `PHP 5.6` to `PHP 7.0` and with `PHP 7.0` started getting database errors from `postgresql` (version 9.5 if that makes any difference) telling that the inserted data violates a constraint check. Run the same code again with `PHP 5.6` and there was no violation. Removed all the checks to see what the parameters actually were and it seemed there were empty strings where `NULL` values were expected. I found a few old and fixed `PHP` bugs where `pg_query()` and `pg_query_params()` converted `NULL` values to empty strings, but this is different. `NULL` only gets converted to an empty string if the params array was looped over with a reference.

**code demonstrating the problem:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO params_test (value, details) VALUES ($1, $2)";

$params = array(null, "insert before looping with a reference");
var_dump($params); echo "<br>";
var_dump(is_null($params[0])); echo "<br>";
$result = pg_query_params($this->connection, $sql, $params);

$params2 = array(null, "insert after looping with a reference");
foreach ($params2 as &$p) {
    // doing nothing
}
unset($p);
var_dump($params2); echo "<br>";
var_dump(is_null($params2[0])); echo "<br>";
$result = pg_query_params($this->connection, $sql, $params2);

echo "NULL equals NULL: "; var_dump($params[0] === $params2[0]); echo "<br>";
```

**output:**

```
array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(36) "insert before looping with reference" } 
bool(true) 
array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> string(67) "insert after looping with a reference" } 
bool(true) 
NULL equals NULL: bool(true)
```

**postgresql log:**

```
2016-04-15 09:28:04 EEST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO params_test (value, details) VALUES ($1, $2)
2016-04-15 09:28:04 EEST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = NULL, $2 = 'insert before looping with a reference'
2016-04-15 09:28:04 EEST LOG:  execute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO params_test (value, details) VALUES ($1, $2)
2016-04-15 09:28:04 EEST DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '', $2 = 'insert after looping with a reference'
```

I would very much appreciate if anyone could explain what is happening here...

Comment: This may be a bug. [Handling of foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach) is certainly changed, but I cannot see how that could cause this. You may submit [a bug to PHP developers](https://bugs.php.net), but until then you could remove `unset($p);` from the foreach (as it does nothing, unless this is just an overly simplified version of the code).

Comment: thanks @pozs. This indeed is an overly simplified version. Without `unset($p);` `var_dump`ing the array looks like this: `array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> &string(37) "insert after looping with a reference" }`. But of course it is enough to unset only after the foreach loop (will edit).

Answer (score 0):

Reported this as a bug and it is fixed already. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72028